# LINQ-to-SQL - when does it access the database?

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2, sql-server-profiler

In my asp.net mvc 2 app I have an action which is rather data-heavy. I'm using linq-to-sql for the queries, while using the repository pattern.
When I check the execution of the action in SQL Server profiler, I find that approximately 60 queries are being executed. My question is - and I hope there is enough infomation in the question to answer it - does asp.net mvc make a full round trip, back and fourth, to the database, for each and every query, or is it that because of the use of linq, there is actually only one round trip ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what your Linq looks like.  It's my understanding that when your result set enumerates you will hit the database.

Comment: Thank you, but could you please clarify - what do you mean by "when your result set enumerates" ? - do you mean to say - when the query returns something like IQueryable or IEnumerable ?

Comment: Enumerating means accessing the results as Chris said below.  It's similar to using the debugger and clicking the Results refresh icon when you are hovering over a collection or an IQueryable.  The results are lazy loaded.  You can access the count and things like that but it doesn't hit the database until you use the results somewhere, hence enumeration.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's one round trip per query, whether that is a LINQ query or raw SQL.  I suppose it depends on what you mean by "each and every query."

To answer your comment above:

var result = LINQ; <--- Query is generated, but not executed

foreach( YourDataType ydt in result ) {  <--- Query executes when you do something with result

...

}

Comment: I'd vote your answer up if I could ... your answer is consistent with a recheck I did: I put a break point in my action and at the same time checked the profiler, it showed that the actual selects were actually executed only at the point where I was using the results of the query. But as far as round trips, I guess it will make a full round trip for each and every select, which is not acceptable when I have as many selects as I have in that action...

Comment: I voted him up.  When you access the results of the collection you are enumerating it.

Comment: Oh by the way, this might be too late, but I had a similar problem to yours with several round trips to the database.  Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822284/more-efficient-linq-query